# removing laravel/public/ from path in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My current path in laravel to index page is

localhost/debeli/laravel/public/

how to make it just

localhost/

Running windows 7, 32-bit
Virtual host XAMPP

I change my xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/debeli/laravel/public/"

but it does not work

Comment: Append `debeli/laravel/public` to your web server's / virtual host's configured document root

Comment: Can you post your `httpd.conf` here?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to create a virtual host for your site and place the files in its public root folder (configurable when you create the virtual host), or place your laravel installation inside root of your main server.

For more details specify your platofrm (what OS are you running).

Answer (score 0):

To serve laravel, navigate to your laravel installation directory in cmd and type 'php artisan serve' it should serve your app to localhost:8000

more info: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick

or create a virtual host point to your public folder (already answered)

or use laravel homestead: more info: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

Answer (score 0):

Inside the xampp folder, you have to search the folder `apache/conf/extra`. Inside that folder you could find a file called `httpd-vhosts.conf`, inside that file you could specify a new virtual host where you map the DocumentRoot to your site folder in htdocs.

Add the following to the bottom of the file : 
`<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/debeli/laravel/public"
   ServerName localhost
   ErrorLog "logs/app-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/app-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>`

Do not forget to restart the apache server!

Kind regards,
Flm